# Where is the mistake - adjacency list?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm getting error when try self reference

```
class Sku(Base, ReprDescrIdMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'SC84'
    id = Column("ID", String, primary_key=True)
    parent_code = Column("PARENTID",String, ForeignKey('sku.id'))
    parent = relationship('Sku', foreign_keys='Sku.parent_code')


sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Sku.parent - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Wherefore? this is work http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class Sku(Base, ReprDescrIdMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'SC84'
    id = Column("ID", String, primary_key=True)
    parent_code = Column("PARENTID",String, ForeignKey(id))
    parent = relationship('Sku', foreign_keys=parent_code)
```

when using `ForeignKey(...)` you should pass the reference key, there's two ways to do this

1. By passing a string with table name and key concatenated with `.` like `ForeignKey("table_name.key")`
2. By passing a Column object like `ForeignKey(key)`

You can only use the method 2 if the `key` was already defined, in other words, if the `ForeignKey(key)` comes after `key = Column(...)`

In my example, I'm using the method 2, I prefer this way in order to code be analyzed by my IDE.

See this [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey.params.column)

Comment: Thanks, it is work. i discouraged when official docs describes another way and this other way doesn't work.

Comment: @0xdeface [The official docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey.params.column) says same thing  I'm saying

Answer (score 0):

The self referencing should be with table name (`__tablename__`) not Object name, following is for ONE-TO-MANY relationship:

```
class Sku(Base, ReprDescrIdMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'SC84'
    id = Column("ID", String, primary_key=True)
    parent_code = Column("PARENTID",String, ForeignKey('SC84.id'))
    # ----------------------------------------------->  ^^^^ __tablename__ here
    children = relationship('Sku')
```

For MANY-TO-ONE relationship:

```
class Sku(Base, ReprDescrIdMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'SC84'
    id = Column("ID", String, primary_key=True)
    parent_code = Column("PARENTID",String, ForeignKey('SC84.id'))
    parent = relationship('Sku', remote_side=['id'])
```

Comment: if use table name i got AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'parent_code'

Comment: AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'PARENTID'

Comment: Are u trying to make ONE-TO-MANY relationship or MANY-TO-ONE?

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship    
class Sku(Base, ReprDescrIdMixin):
        __tablename__ = 'SC84'
        id = Column("ID", String, primary_key=True)
        parent_code = Column("PARENTID",String, ForeignKey('sku.id'))
        parent = relationship('Sku', lazy="joined", foreign_keys=[parent_code])
```